# Is there a way to scan an entire column based on one cell in another column and pull out a value of the corresponding column?

Tags: excel, vba

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 6 | 5649 |
| 3 | 8 | 10 | 9853 |
| 5 | 2 | 7 | 1354 |

I have two worksheets, for example column A in sheet 1 and columns B-D in sheet 2.

What I want to do is to take one value in Column A, and scan both columns B and C and it is between those two values, then display the corresponding value from column D in a new worksheet.

There could be multiple matches for each of the cell in column A and if there is no match, to skip it and not have anything displayed. Is there a way to code this and somehow create a loop to do all of column A?  I tried using this formula, but I think it only matches for each row and not how I want it to.

```
=IF(AND([PQ.xlsx]Sheet1!$A2>=[PQ.xlsx]Sheet2!$B2,[PQ.xlsx]Sheet1!$A2<[PQ.xlsx]Sheet2!$C2),[PQ.xlsx]Sheet2!$D$2,"")
```

How do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: So if it matches on multiple how would you want the output ie, a concatenated value like `5649, 1254` or spread over multiple cells with one value in each cell?

Comment: @BigBen I have Excel 2016

Comment: @ScottCraner I would like for it to have it spread over with one value in each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive if I understood exactly what you intended.  In this sheet, I have taken each value in A:A and checked to see if it was between any pair of values in B:C, and then returned each value from D:D where that is true.  I did keep this all on a single tab for ease of demonstration, but you can easily change the references to match your own layout.  I tested in Excel and then transferred to this Google Sheet, but the functions should work the same.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-RR1UZC8-AVnRoj1h8JLbnXewmzyDQKuKU49Ef-1F1Y/edit#gid=0

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTER($D$2:$D$15, ($A2>=$B$2:$B$15)*($A2<=$C$2:$C$15))), "")
```

So what I have done is FILTEREDed column D on the two conditions that Ax is >= B:B and <= C:C, then TRANSPOSED the result so that it lays out horizontally instead of vertically, and finally wrapped it in an error trap to avoid #CALC where there are no results returned.

I added some random data to test with.  Let me know if this is what you were looking at, or if I misunderstood your intent.

---

**SUPPORT FOR EXCEL VERSIONS WITHOUT DYNAMIC ARRAY FUNCTIONS**

You can duplicate this effect with array functions in pre-dynamic array versions of Excel.  This is an array function, so it has be finished with SHFT+ENTER.  Put it in F2, SHFT+ENTER, and then drag it to fill F2:O15:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$15, SMALL(IF(($A2>=$B$2:$B$15)*($A2<=$C$2:$C$15), ROW($A$2:$A$15)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$15))+1), COLUMNS($F$2:F2))),"")
```

reformatted for easier explanation:

```
=IFERROR(
  INDEX(
    $D$2:$D$15, 
    SMALL(
      IF(
        ($A2>=$B$2:$B$15)*($A2<=$C$2:$C$15), 
        ROW($A$2:$A$15) - MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$15))+1
      ), 
      COLUMNS($F$2:F2)
    )
  ),
"")
```

From the inside out: `ROW($A$2:$A$15)` creates an array from 2 to 15, and `MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$15))+1` scales it so that no matter which row the range starts in it will return the numbers starting from 1, so `ROW($A$2:$A$15) - MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$15))+1` returns an array from 1 to 14.

We use this as the second argument in the IF clause, what to return if TRUE.  For the first argument, the logical conditions, we take the same two conditions from the original formula: `($A2>=$B$2:$B$15)*($A2<=$C$2:$C$15)`.  As before, this returns an array of true/false values.  So the output of the entire IF clause is an array that consists of the row numbers where the conditions are true or FALSE where the conditions aren't met.

Take that array and pass it to SMALL.  SMALL takes an array and returns the kth smallest value from the array.  You'll use `COLUMNS($F$2:F2)` to determine k.  COLUMNS returns the number of columns in the range, and since the first cell in the range reference is fixed and the second cell is dynamic, the range will expand when you drag the formula.  What this will do is give you the 1st, 2nd, ... kth row numbers that contain matches, since FALSE values aren't returned by SMALL (as a matter of fact they generate an error, which is why the whole formula is wrapped in IFERROR).

Finally, we pass the range with the numbers we want to return (D2:D15 in this case) to INDEX along with the row number we got from SMALL, and INDEX will return the value from that row.

So FILTER is a lot simpler to look at, but you can get it done in an older version.  This will also work in Google Sheets, and I added a second tab there with this formula, but array formulas work a little different there.  Instead of using SHFT+ENTER to indicate an array formula, Sheets just wraps the formula in ARRAY_FORMULA().  Other than that, the two formulas are the same.

Since FALSE values aren't considered, it will skip those.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for, but I have excel 2016, I don't think there is a filter formula there.

Comment: I was under the impression that FILTER was available starting in 2016, but I could be wrong.  Check and see and if you don't have it I'll give you a different way.

Comment: I checked and I don't seem to see it there

Comment: @Kuro: take a look at that edit and see if that works for you.

Comment: Yes, that works great, thank you!